# Como descargar un archivo local con nextjs

Tags: reactjs, web, archivo, nextjs, download

Me encuentro probando diferentes soluciones y librerias, pero no consigo lo que necesito, el "desafio" es el siguiente, estoy trabajando con nextjs, tengo un archivo pdf en /src/public/pdf/CV.pdf y necesito que al precionar un boton este se descargue en la computadora del usuario, desde ya muchas gracias y espero que puedan ayudarme , saludos!

He probado solucionarlo de las siguientes maneras:

```
<a href="public/pdf/CV.pdf" download='cv.pdf' >Download CV</a>
<Link href="public/pdf/CV.pdf" download='cv.pdf' >Download CV</Link>
```

Cuando utilozo el elemento "a" el navegador intenta descargar, pero en la sección de descarga me muestra un error que dice "Interrupted: No file".

Por otra parte cuando utilizo "Link" me redirije a un 404

Comment: y que has intentado, lee [ask], recuerda que toda pregunta debe tener una demostracion de esfuerzo, osea un [example]

Comment: Intente utilizar la etiqueta "a" y "Link" con el atributo href enlazando a mi archivo pdf, y el atributo download como el nombre de la descarga, tambien intente importar el pdf y poner esa variable en href, pero solo admita string.

Tambien intente conseguir una libreria que lo hiciera por mi,
y la mayoria es para hacer un fetch a un archivo que no se encuentra en su directorio local para despues compartirlo, esto tampoco me dio resultado, si les gustaria ver algo de codigo puedo editar la publicacion para que vean mejor lo que intente

Comment: Seria bueno que expliques a que te refieres con `no consigo lo que necesite`. Deberias describir que esta ocurriendo al hacer click con los botones / links que has intentado crear (te tira un error 404? no hace nada? etc)

Comment: as intentado simplemente ir a la ruta que muestran en href? con click derecho ir a abrir enlace en una nueva pestana?

Comment: acabo de probar y me lleva a un 404, con cualquiera de las 2 etiquetas, pienso que talvez se usa una libreria que desconozco para hacer esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js por defecto va a buscar la ruta en los archivos públicos primero. Lo que debes hacer es remover el `/public`.

```
<Link href="/pdf/CV.pdf" >Download CV</Link>
```

Si dicha ruta existe para un archivo estático, Next.js lo va a mostrar.

Para más info revisa [sus docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)!

Comment: Exelente, esto funciona, creo que parte del problema es que yo tenia la carpeta `/public` dentro de src y debe estar en la raiz, y para lograr el efecto exacto que buscaba (descargar directamente al precionar) use la siguiente linea.. .
`<Link href="/pdf/CV.pdf" target='_blank' download='cv.pdf'>Descargar CV</Link>`